# Integrating from where I left off and where to go next?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, complex-integration

$$
I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x \cdot e^{-2x}}{\sqrt{e^x-1}} \, dx
$$

Let $(u=\sqrt{e^x-1})$ which gives $(\ln(u^2+1)=x) $ and $(\frac{2u \, du}{u^2+1}= dx)$.

The new bounds of integration are still 0 and infinity.

Now we have

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(u^{2}+1)}{\left(e^{2ln(u^{2}+1)}\right) \cdot u} \cdot \frac{2u}{u^{2}+1} \, du
$$

Bounds: From 0 to infinity.

After simplification using log rules, we have $(\frac{\ln(u^2+1)}{(u^2+1)^3})$ and the $(u)$ cancels, leaving us with

$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(u^2+1)}{(u^2+1)^3} \, du \quad \text{or} \quad \int_0^\infty 2 \ln(u^2+1) \cdot (u^2+1)^{-3} \, du
$

Then using $(u=\tan(w))$, $(du=\sec(w)^2)$, and

$
ln(u^2+1) \rightarrow \ln(\tan(w)^2+1) \rightarrow \ln(1/\sec(w)^2) \rightarrow -2 \ln(\cos(w))
$

we are left with

$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} -4 \ln(\cos(w)) \cdot \cos(w)^4 \, dw
$

Would using complex analysis be appropriate to solve? If so, how would I evaluate the closed form of this integral that I left off on? If not, how do I consider the integral from where I left off?
Thanks

Comment: Please surround your LaTeX with single or double dollar signs ($) so that the math renders correctly

Comment: Just Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use displayed formulas in title lines.

Comment: @Marek What is going on?  The original integral was $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x-1)^{3/2}}\,dx$.  I provided a solution.  Then, I noticed that a revision was made.  So, which is it??

Comment: My apologies. I meant for the one that it is revised to. However, I am also working on an integral, which you provided a solution to—much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE:**  The original post asked to evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x-1)^{3/2}}\,dx$.  The following development began before any revisions.  However,the methodology used here can be applied to the integral in the revised post (That solution is presented in the **BONUS** section).

---

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x-1)^{3/2}}\,dx&=\int_1^\infty \frac{\log^2(x)}{(x-1)^{3/2}}\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^2(x+1)}{x^{3/2}}\,dx\tag2\\\\
&=4\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x+1)}{x^{1/2}(x+1)}\,dx\tag3\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{(x+1)^t}{x^{1/2}}\,dx\right)\right|_{t=-1}\tag4\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(2\int_0^\infty (x^2+1)^t\,dx\right)\right|_{t=-1}\tag5\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sec^{2t+2}(x)\,dx\right)\right|_{t=-1}\tag6\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(B(1/2,-t-1/2)\right)\right|_{t=-1}\tag7\\\\
&=4\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(-t-1/2)}{\Gamma(-t)}\right)\right|_{t=-1}\tag8\\\\
&=4\sqrt\pi\left.\left(-\frac{\Gamma(-t-1/2)\psi(-t-1/2)}{\Gamma(-t)}\right)\right|_{t=-1}\\\\
&+4\sqrt\pi\left.\left(\frac{\Gamma(-t)\Gamma(-t-1/2)\psi(-t)}{\Gamma^2(-t)}\right)\right|_{t=-1}\tag9\\\\
&=4\sqrt\pi\left(-\frac{\sqrt\pi (-\gamma-\log(4))}{1}+\frac{(1)\sqrt\pi (-\gamma)}{(1)^2}\right)\tag{10}\\\\
&=4\pi \log(4)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

---

---

**NOTES:**

In arriving at the right-hand side of $(1)$, we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto \log(x)$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto x+1$

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we integrated by parts with $u=\log^2(x+1)$ and $v=-2x^{-1/2}$

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we employed Feynman's trick.

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto x^2$

In going from $(5)$ to $(6)$, we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto \tan(x)$

In going from $(6)$ to $(7)$, we made use of an integral representation of the Beta function

In going from $(7)$ to $(8)$, we made use of the relationship betwen the Beta function and the Gamma function

In going from $(8)$ to $(9)$, we took the derivative and used the relationship $\Gamma'(z)=\Gamma(z)\psi(z)$, we $\psi(z)$ is the Digamma function.

In arriving at $(10)$ we evaluated the derivative at $t=-1$ and used the fact that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$, $\Gamma(1)=1$, $\psi(1/2)=-\gamma-\log(4)$, and $\psi(1)=-\gamma$

---

---

**BONUS:**

I thought that I would present the companion solution, which is solution to the currently posted question. Using the same approach as presented in the previous solution we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-2x}}{(e^x-1)^{1/2}}\,dx&=\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^3(x-1)^{1/2}}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x+1)}{(x+1)^3x^{1/2}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{(x+1)^t}{x^{1/2}}\,dx\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(2\int_0^\infty (x^2+1)^t\,dx\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sec^{2t+2}(x)\,dx\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(B(1/2,-t-1/2)\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left.\left(\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(-t-1/2)}{\Gamma(-t)}\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&=\sqrt\pi\left.\left(-\frac{\Gamma(-t-1/2)\psi(-t-1/2)}{\Gamma(-t)}\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&+\sqrt\pi\left.\left(\frac{\Gamma(-t)\Gamma(-t-1/2)\psi(-t)}{\Gamma^2(-t)}\right)\right|_{t=-3}\\\\
&=\sqrt\pi\left(-\frac{(3\sqrt\pi/4) (8/3-\gamma-\log(4))}{2}+\frac{(2)(3\sqrt\pi/4) (3/2-\gamma)}{(2)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{16}\left( 6\log(4)-7\right)
\end{align}$$

And we are done (again)!

Comment: Thank you. I was also stuck on this.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to upvote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Comment: Note that the methodology herein can be applied to evaluate the  integral in the revised post.

Comment: Appreciate the solution. What was the intuition behind using the Feynman technique, was there a pattern or something that stood out to you?

Comment: Well, yes.  When I see a logarithm in the numerator, it sometimes prompts me to replace it with a derivative with respect to $t$ of $x^t$.

Comment: Would the other part of the Feynman technique with the Lebesgue Rule and partial derivative, be able to solve this or does it not apply?

Comment: What "other part" do you mean.  And do you mean Leibniz?

Comment: Disregard that, but yes Leibniz, I realized you can’t do that in this case. Without the way you did it, trying to do it the elementary techniques got very tedious.

Comment: I wonder if you can put the step explanations inline with `\tag`?

Comment: @qwr What do you mean.  There are ten steps with explanations.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{x \cdot e^{-2x}}{\sqrt{e^x-1}} \, \mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x \cdot e^{-\frac52x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}} \, \mathrm dx\\ \\
&=&\int_0^\infty x \cdot e^{-\frac52x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n-\frac12}{n}e^{-nx} \, \mathrm dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n-\frac12}{n}\int_0^\infty xe^{-(n+\frac52)x} \, \mathrm dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{n-\frac12}{n}}{(n+\frac52)^2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{16} \pi  (12 \ln 2-7).
\end{eqnarray}
$$